# Set BitmapField's image on Thread with BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, bitmapfield

I am trying to set a `BitmapField`'s image using the `setImage()` method. It works fine, but when I try to do it on a thread it throws a `IllegalStateException` and it doesn't work.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the update in the event dispatch thread (or at least get the lock).  The easiest way to do it is with the following code pattern:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ... your code here ...
    }
});
```